# Comparing Strings when one could be null

Tags: java, android, string-comparison

am presently trying to get a response from a server which contains a response code of "00,02" i used an if and else if statement to perform an action for each of this response but am getting null pointer for the first if statement

```
if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("02")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("00")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: It means, `str` is null. How are you assigning value to `str`?

Comment: am getting the values directly from a json response, if the response does not have a responseCode then am to toast the response message out to the user, that is what the last else is meant to be for

Comment: In that case your first check should be for null. Check my answer.

Comment: You might want a unique message for each case, if the code is to do anything useful...

Comment: I'd recommend you change the title, it's quite misleading and very vague.

Comment: @njzk2 - don't close a question with answers which usefully address its **specific issue** as a duplicate of a generic one which only provides broad advice, **especially when the poster had already done what was advised there** by specifying the exact location of the NPE even from the original posted form of their question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A null-safe way of comparing strings would be:

```
if ("02".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
    ...
}
```

So just flip the strings in each of your conditions and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Update your condition like this

```
if(str == null || str.length() == 0){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("02")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("00")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    // Unknown code from server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TextUtils.isEmpty(str)` function like so:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)){

    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("02")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("00")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This function basically does this for you:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Which you could've done yourself, but it might be clearer this way.

Comment: also tried this and it worked, lol seems i have a lot of options

Comment: @henry enjoy coding, this was quite an easy question , that's why you ended up with multiple good answers.